# how to add only volume controls on HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video

I want to use HTML5 video tag, but in this case i want only volume controls... please help me

```
<video controls id="myMovie" width="600" height="600" loop preload="auto" >
<source src="any file.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

<source src="any file.mp4" type='video/mp4' />         
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you can selectively hide the controls but there is way to do it.

You can first hide all the controls by removing `controls` attribute from the video element.

Demo here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop

Then, you can use your own buttons to increase or decrease the volume using javascript. You can get the sample code here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

JS:

```
// volume buttons
document.getElementById("volDn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    setVol(-.1); // down by 10%
}, false);
document.getElementById("volUp").addEventListener("click", function () {
    setVol(.1); // up by 10%
}, false);


// change volume based on incoming value 
    function setVol(value) {
        var vol = video.volume;
        vol += value;
        //  test for range 0 - 1 to avoid exceptions
        if (vol >= 0 && vol <= 1) {
            // if valid value, use it
            video.volume = vol;
        } else {
            // otherwise substitute a 0 or 1
            video.volume = (vol < 0) ? 0 : 1;                        
        }
    }
```